# спарсить самозакрывающийся тег

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlparser

Использую XmlPullParser. Так вот он не парсит самозакрывающийся тег, просто пропускает его, даже isEmptyElementTag не помогает. Что делать?

Дан такой XML файл

```
<phone>
    <id>1</id>
    <company/> // его надо спарсить
    <model>Galaxy</model>
    <price>18000</price>
</phone>
```

Необходимо спарсить оттуда самозакрывающийся тег company и когда парсер наткнется на этот то в лог должно выводиться сообщение, но этого по каким то неведомым причинам не происходит. Что делать?

```
    try {
        XmlPullParser xpp = prepareXpp();
        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            switch (xpp.getEventType()) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if (xpp.isEmptyElementTag()) {
                        tagName = "company"; }

                      break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    if (tagName.equals("company")) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Пустой тег"  );
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: лог в кейс со `START_TAG` перенести?

Comment: @zRrr не помогает

Comment: мне кажется, что проблема не в том, что он самозакрывающийся, а в том, что он пустой